# Searching inside JSONs in Chrome devtools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a possibility to searching inside all JSON objects from all available responses in the network tab? Currently it works, but very randomly and isn't much reliable. Sometimes and especially in a smaller responses it's ok but when you have more assets almost always looking for, e.g. specific params value ends unsuccessfully. Do you know any smart solution of that issue? I've checked and first question associated with it has already few years and Google devs still haven't responded.

Example: I have object ID in response body, but cannot find it by search <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one way is to save all the response in a file (manually or automatically, if possibile by using a browser extension).

After you have stored all the responses in a file you can parse the file and find things inside the file by using a script or just regex.

You can save the answers (as HAR file) manually (I use firefox) by right clicking on a network response inside the developer console panel.
I found that is the same for chrome.

Look here:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference

I didn't search if there is a way to automatically store all the responses received by a browser. I'm not sure, but I think it isn't possible :/